# How to remove a tag from table by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML table produced by a php loop (Contains  multiple rows). I want to remove all the `a` tags in `td` tag where `td` tag ID is equal to 1 or another thing.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID: 1</td>
        <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>
                <a href='http://localhost/www/GestIEFP/index.php/admin/groups/index/delete/1' title='Remover Grupo' class="delete-row" ><span class='delete-icon'></span></a>
                <a href='http://localhost/www/GestIEFP/index.php/admin/groups/index/edit/1' title='Editar Grupo'><span class='edit-icon'></span></a>
                <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('table').find("td:contains('ID: 1')")
    .each ( function () {
        $('a').remove();
    })
})
```

Any solution?

Comment: Based on your example html, what do you want to remove?

Comment: There are no links in your table cell that contains ID:1,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't exactly clear but I think this is what you want:

```
$("td:contains('ID: 1')").next().find('a').remove()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
    $('table').find("td:contains('ID: 1')")
    .each ( function () {
        $(this).next('td').find('a').remove();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("table td:contains('ID: 1')").closest("tr").find("a").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajvra/4/

Comment: @fliespl yes you were really fast with your comment. It should work now .D

Comment: While this does answer the question, OP should note that lookup like this is quite heavy and will result in performance issues on a large document, as it will need to traverse all the table cells and compare the contents to the said pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the HTML that your php loop produces, i would suggest changing HTML rather than dealing with this result.

Specifically, i would suggest adding `id` to `tr` element, that would be much more efficient for traversing html with javascript afterwards.

Suppose, you change your html to look like this: `<tr id="item-1">` where 1 is your item id..

Then, with jQuery you could access it by `$('#item-1')`, and removing all links would simply be `$('#item-1 a').remove()`